# Same code for multiple functions, how do I shorten this?

Tags: javascript

I've created 3 functions:  for 3 health bars I made. These functions actually have the same code, so I want to shorten these. I tried to make an general function with parameters and then call the function. But I don't know what to write in this general function to make all the three health bars work.

Sorry if it sounds a little vague. Hope someone can help.

Comment: If this code works, and you want a review of all of the aspects of the code, you should read the help center of [codereview.se] to see if it's on topic there.

Comment: Does the code in if else contains full of your code or just short version?

Comment: It contains the full code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why you have so many `else if` when the code is the same ? You should regroups your intervals, why you only have 20 length intervals ?

You can also regroup the same logic under a function like this one below.

```
function globalFunction(value, id) {
    if (value > 0) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = value--;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-5-v1.gif";
    }
    if (value >= 40 && value <= 60) {
        document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-3-v2.gif";
    }
}

function hungerFunction() {
    globalFunction(hungerTotal, "meter-hunger")
}

function thirstFunction() {
    globalFunction(thirstTotal, "meter-thirst")
}

function funFunction() {
    globalFunction(funTotal, "meter-fun")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the only different between 3 functions total and id, you can create generalFunction and call it in each function as below.

```js
function generalFunction(total,id) {

  if (total >= 100) {
    document.getElementById("id").value = total--;


  } else if ((total <= 100) && (total >= 80)) {
    document.getElementById("id").value = total--;


  } else if ((total <= 80) && (total >= 60)) {
    document.getElementById("id").value = total--;


  } else if ((total <= 60) && (total >= 40)) {
    document.getElementById("id").value = total--;
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-3-v2.gif";


  } else if ((total <= 40) && (total >= 20)) {
    document.getElementById("id").value = total--;


  } else if ((total <= 20) && (total > 0)) {
    document.getElementById("id").value = total--;


  } else if (total == 0) {
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-5-v1.gif";
  }
}
   
function hungerFunction() {
  generalFunction(hungerTotal,"meter-hunger")
}

function thirstFunction() {
  generalFunction(thirstTotal,"meter-thirst")
}

function funFunction() {
  generalFunction(funTotal,"meter-fun")
}
```

Comment: you could simplify your `generalFunction` a lot more

Comment: You right. But the question is about how to show to shorten code when hungerFunction(), thirstFunction(), funFunction()  seem to be similar. I am not sure he has full of his code in if else block or not. I'll update my comment after clarify his question.

Comment: Alright, but if he has not all of his code in `if/else` maybe it is not "regroupable".

Comment: Note that this approach does not preserve the changes to `hungerTotal`, `thirstTotal`, `funTotal` - see my answer for one way to do that.

Comment: The way you do is only thing shorter is not creating `hungerFunction`,  `thirstFunction `, `funFunction ` function to call  `generalFunction `. My angle is try to move same code to general one and then keep same layout to try to make him to understand easily.

Comment: @TonyNguyen I mean, that's just completely wrong. Your code will break his game because the `total--` does not actually decrease `hungerTotal`, so they will stay maxed out. I think you didn't actually read my answer, by the end our code looks quite different. Notice in particular that the way I call my functions is by assigning them, in your case it would be like `hungerTotal = generalFunction(hungerTotal,"meter-hunger")`

Answer (score 0):

Just make decision using function argument like this:

```js
function myallfunctions(arg) {
    document.getElementById(arg).value = 70;
}

myallfunctions("input1");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
```

Also you need study about functions.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding repetition means identifying the *common elements* in each repetitive section, and extracting those into a separate function. Those parts which are different between each repetitive section should be either handled outside of the function, or made parameters into the function.

In this case, the common elements seem to be everything except for the element ID ("meter-hunger", "meter-thirst", "meter-fun") and the variable being used (hungerTotal, thirstTotal, funTotal). So, make those two parts *parameters* into a new function, and call that new function instead.

```
function drainStatus(id,stat) {
  if (stat >= 100) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 100) && (stat >= 80)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 80) && (stat >= 60)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 60) && (stat >= 40)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-3-v2.gif";
  } else if ((stat <= 40) && (stat >= 20)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 20) && (stat > 0)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if (stat == 0) {
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-5-v1.gif";
  }
}
```

There is one issue you run into with this: Passing any of the `_Total` variables into this function will pass by value, so modifying the `stat` parameter won't modify the outer variable. To fix this I would just have the function return the new value, and make the caller responsible for assigning it back.

```
function drainStatus(id,stat) {
  if (stat >= 100) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 100) && (stat >= 80)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 80) && (stat >= 60)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 60) && (stat >= 40)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-3-v2.gif";
  } else if ((stat <= 40) && (stat >= 20)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if ((stat <= 20) && (stat > 0)) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  } else if (stat == 0) {
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-5-v1.gif";
  }
  return stat;
}

setInterval(function() {
  hungerTotal = drainStatus("meter-hunger",hungerTotal);
  thirstTotal = drainStatus("meter-thirst",thirstTotal);
  funTotal = drainStatus("meter-fun",funTotal);
}, 300);
```

If you're wanting to avoid repetition there's one more thing you can do here. Notice that **every single one** of your if-statements results in the exact same line, except for `if (stat == 0)`... so you can just invert this, and execute that line if stat is `!= 0`.

```
function drainStatus(id,stat) {
  if (stat > 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = stat--;
  }
  if ((stat <= 60) && (stat >= 40)) {
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-3-v2.gif";
  } else if (stat == 0) {
    document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = document.getElementById("status-tamagotchi").src = "images/monster-state-5-v1.gif";
  }
  return stat;
}
```